# When zooming out page divs are moving

Tags: html, css, zooming

I know that there are a lot of questions and answers about that, but still I can't figure out how to apply to my website. Problem is when zooming out page divs are moving where they don't belong.

Here is picture: http://prnt.sc/c1fz87

Live: http://minecube.lt/paslaugos/

CSS: http://pastebin.com/aCgUyZxV

HTML: http://pastebin.com/WgrHwXpw

And default bootstrap 3.3.7: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a `background-size` to your body style

```
background-size:cover;
```

Hope its help you